# Setting up user to download files with no shell access

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp, 14.10

I've created a user and set its shell to `/usr/sbin/nologin`. As expected, a PuTTY connection closes immediately after connection. When trying to get WinSCP to connect with the SFTP protocol, it says the connection was refused and asks if an SFTP server is running. Using the SCP protocol unsurprisingly doesn't work either.

I installed RSSH and set the user's shell to `/usr/bin/rssh` and got exactly the same result. PuTTY dropped the connection immediately, SFTP asked if the SFTP server was running, and SCP wouldn't work.

I set the user's shell to `/bin/bash` and both SFTP and SCP worked fine, just like with my main user.

What am I doing wrong? How can I set the user so that it can download files off the server but does not have shell access?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man sshd_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html):

```
ForceCommand
         Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand,
         ignoring any command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if
         present.               ...           Specifying a command
         of “internal-sftp” will force the use of an in-process sftp
         server that requires no support files when used with
         ChrootDirectory.
```

So edit your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add something like this:

```
Match User username
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Use `Match` so that only the required users/groups are affected.

---

The full description of `ForceCommand` says:

```
             ...    The command is invoked by using the user's login shell
         with the -c option.  This applies to shell, command, or subsystem
         execution.
```

However, as `internal-sftp` is in-process, this will work even if `/usr/bin/nologin` or `/bin/false` are used as the login shell.